# Meteor: how use data from an Http call in templates

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, xmlhttprequest

I make a call in Http main.js and this returns me to my console "Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'set' of null"
Can not retrieve information from my http call outside the function itself.
Thanks for you help.

```
Template.prod.onCreated(function prodOnCreated() {
var tmpl = this;
tmpl.data = new ReactiveVar;

HTTP.call( 'GET', 'https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/electronics/products/search/?query=:price-asc:category:575', {}, function( error, response ) {
if ( error )
console.log( error );
 else {
console.log( response.data.products[0].code); // that works: display  "2140285"
tmpl.data.set(response.data);// Doesn't work: message in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of null"
}
});
});


Template.prod.helpers({
data: function() {
console.log('Hi you are in the data function');
return  Template.instance().data.get();
}
});
```

**The console display:**

> main.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of
>   null(anonymous function) @ main.js:40(anonymous function) @
>   httpcall_client.js:83(anonymous function) @
>   underscore.js?hash=8de51f9…:784xhr.onreadystatechange @
>   httpcall_client.js:172

Comment: `tmpl.data = new ReactiveVar();` see paranthesis

Comment: Hi @Sasikanth I corrected it, and i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a package using below

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

then you can initialize reactivevar like

```
tmpl.data = new ReactiveVar();
```

Comment: This package is already included in version 1.3 of meteor:
In the header of the JS: import {} ReactiveVar from 'meteor / reactive-var';

Comment: It should be `import { ReactiveVar }  from 'meteor / reactive-var'` right?

Comment: in fact reactive var works, for example:
    Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
      // counter starts at 0
      this.counter = new ReactiveVar(5);
      console.log(this.counter.get()); //it works : display 5
    });

Comment: small repo with reproduction might help